# Install a Nuget package in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, nuget-package

How can I install a Nuget Package in Visual Studio Code? I know in Visual Studio, we  can do this through the Nuget Package Manager console, but how do I do it in VS Code?

Comment: i would prefer console because the extension has no good reviews

Comment: The way i do it, is to use nuget.org, search, and just use the PackageReference (located with the other installment options). Works pretty good, and you get a good UI for the nuget it self.

Answer (score 337):

From the command line or the terminal windows in VS Code editor:

```
dotnet add <PROJECT> package <PACKAGE_NAME> [options]
```

Ex.:

```
dotnet add MyApp package MySql.Data -Version 8.0.31
```

See this [article by Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TryingOutDotnetNewTemplateUpdatesAndCsprojWithVS2017.aspx)

Comment: Note that this will work only on the new csproj-based .Net Core SDK 1.0, but not on the old project.json-based preview versions.

Comment: That unfortunately does not support search or auto-complete. That is, you have to know the exact package name spelling.

Comment: You can go to [nuget.org](https://www.nuget.org/) to search packages as you might otherwise do in Visual Studio, then use the command line to install the package you want.

Comment: Notes: (1) I had to use `--version` or `-v` ( not `-Version`); (2) I had to include the `.csproj` file extension. Full example that worked for me: `dotnet add MyApp.csproj package MySql.Data --version 8.0.31`

Answer (score 116):

**Edit**: From the comments below:

> 22 June 2019: "This extension is now unpublished from Marketplace. You can choose to uninstall it." 2¢. – ruffin Jun 22 '19 at 13:23

> The provided link above points to ".Net Core Project Manager (Nuget)" - try: [marketplace.visualstudio.com/…](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jmrog.vscode-nuget-package-manager) – samis Oct 3 '19 at 16:14

---

You can use the [NuGet Package Manager](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ksubedi.net-core-project-manager) extension.

After you've installed it, to add a package, press Ctrl+Shift+P, and type `>nuget` and press Enter:

[image]

Type a part of your package's name as search string:

[image]

Choose the package:

[image]

And finally the package version (you probably want the newest one):

[image]

Comment: This extension appears to not support the new workspaces feature

Comment: This extension seems back on the marketplace, just installed it and works fine for me.

Comment: 22 June 2019: "_This extension is now unpublished from Marketplace. You can choose to uninstall it._" 2¢.

Comment: The provided link above points to *".Net Core Project Manager (Nuget)"* - try: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jmrog.vscode-nuget-package-manager

Answer (score 41):

You can do it easily using "vscode-nuget-package-manager".

Go to the marketplace and install this. After That:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> (and skip 2)
2. Type ">"
3. Then select "Nuget Package Manager:Add Package"
4. Enter package name Ex: Dapper
5. select package name and version
6. Done.

Answer (score 39):

[`Nuget Gallery`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=patcx.vscode-nuget-gallery) provides a GUI similar to the full Visual Studio. See below.

[image]

**How To Use:**

1. Install `Nuget Gallery` from extension marketplace.
2. Launch from the menu bar `View > Command Palette` or ⇧⌘P (Ctrl+Shift+P on Windows and Linux). Type `Nuget: Open Gallery`.
3. The GUI above is displayed. You can filter just like in regular Visual Studio.
4. Make sure the `.csproj file` checkbox is selected, select version from dropdown, and click install button.

**UPDATE**

Earlier versions, as noted in the comments, had an issue where the `.csproj` checkbox was not visible when a package in the csproj file was [missing a version number](https://github.com/pcislo/vscode-nuget-gallery/issues/15#issuecomment-596127291) like below.

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
```

This has been fixed in newer versions of the extension so if you have an older version with this issue, please update it to the latest version.

Comment: Ahh, this is interesting. There is no `.csproj` file tick option in the current version. Maybe that's what my problem is. https://github.com/pcislo/vscode-nuget-gallery/issues/15

Comment: Hi @woter324, the problem of the checkbox not showing was identified as some packages in the `.csproj` not having version numbers. See [issue comment](https://github.com/pcislo/vscode-nuget-gallery/issues/15#issuecomment-596127291). I've updated my answer to include that.

Comment: *Thanks! That was just what I needed to be able to install the Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility package!* This Nuget Gallery actually works with .NET Core 3.1.2! So now I can use OleDbConnection to open a connection to a MS Access Database, while using .NET Core for the other things in Visual Studio Code! Cool!

Comment: I have tested the latest version and it no longer has an issue with missing version numbers

Comment: What if you wanted to install the nuget package for a specific project if you have multiple projects in one solution? Would there be multiple csproj checkboxes?

Comment: @Florent yes there would be several csproj checkboxes if you have multiple projects.

Answer (score 30):

Open extensions menu (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>), and search ".NuGet Package Manager".

Comment: Strange this manager cant find Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel. Below solution works.

Comment: Doesn't work any more since the migration to .csproj file format.

Comment: I can't see that extension when searching for it.

Answer (score 16):

Example for .csproj file

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="7.0.7-m61" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Just get package name and version number from NuGet and add to .csproj then save. You will be prompted to run restore that will import new packages.

Comment: I'm sure this works but having to edit the XML manually seems a shame.

Comment: True, but VS Code is free (and really meant as an editor) so I'm not complaining. It would be different if I had to do this in VS.

Comment: Fair point. So are you editing C# projects entirely in VSCode without any version of Visual Studio installed? Or creating the project in Visual Studio (with sln + csproj files) and then just using VSCode as an editor? I'm guessing if you just use `dotnet` and VSCode then why would you even need those project files.

Comment: No, I actually utilize Visual Studio 2010 & 2015. Prefer 2010 though. All my real coding is also stored in Git repositories. VS Code is more to play around with on my Ubuntu system.

Comment: This is a problem with MS using XML for csproj files instead of something user friendly like yaml.

Answer (score 16):

[nuget package manager gui](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=aliasadidev.nugetpackagemanagergui) extension is a GUI tool that lets you easily update/remove/install packages from Nuget server for .NET Core/.Net 5 projects

**> To install new package:**

1. Open your project workspace in VSCode
2. Open the Command Palette (Ctrl+Shift+P)
3. Select > Nuget Package Manager GUI
4. Click **Install New Package**

[image]

For update/remove the packages click **Update/Remove Packages**

[image]

Comment: That's plain beautiful

Answer (score 10):

If you're working with .net core, you can use the dotnet CLI, for instance

```
dotnet add package <package name>
```

Answer (score 8):

1. Install [NuGet Package Manager](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jmrog.vscode-nuget-package-manager)
2. `Ctrl+Shift+P` on Windows or `Command+Shift+P` on Mac
3. Search for NuGet Package Manager: Add Package
4. Enter package name i.e. AutoMapper
5. Select package & version
6. Restore if needed

Answer (score 5):

The answers above are good, but insufficient if you have more than 1 project (.csproj) in the same folder.

First, you easily add the "PackageReference" tag to the .csproj file (either manually, by using the nuget package manager or by using the dotnet add package command).

But then, you need to run the "restore" command manually so you can tell it which project you are trying to restore (if I just clicked the restore button that popped up, nothing happened).
You can do that by running:

```
dotnet restore Project-File-Name.csproj
```

And that installs the package

Answer (score 3):

Modify your project.json or *.csproj file. Add a dependency entry with the name of the package and the version desired.

JSON example:

```
{
   "dependencies" : {

     "AutoMapper": "5.2.0"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Go to folder that have a sln file.
Open a terminal (like cmd)

```
dotnet add package <package name>
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can use .NET Add Command**

**Usage:**
dotnet add [PROJECT] [command] [options]

**Arguments:**
*PROJECT:*  The project file to operate on. If a file is not specified, the command will search the current directory for one.

*Options:*
-?, -h, --help  Show command line help.

**Commands:**

*package <PACKAGE_NAME>*    Add a NuGet package reference to the project.

*reference <PROJECT_PATH>*  Add a project-to-project reference to the project.