# Error in Visual Studio Code Dotnet Core C#: "The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found", but build succeeds

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-code, .net-core, omnisharp

When trying to work with Visual Studio Code on a C# DotNet Core MVC application, I am having a lot of trouble getting visual studio code to work. It is having trouble finding anything related to C#, marking even 'Using System;' as invalid, saying it can't find it.

However, when I run a Dotnet build, it succeeds with no warnings or errors and the project runs.

My project.json:

```
 {
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "buildOptions": {
    "debugType": "portable",
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.1.0",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design": {
      "version": "1.1.0",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.1.0"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.1": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
          "type": "platform",
          "version": "1.1.0"
        }
      },
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  }
}
```

Any ideas? I'm really pulling my hair out with this one.

Answer (score 144):

Sometimes C# for Visual Studio Code (powered by OmniSharp) becomes confused.

Try restarting OmniSharp. Here are two ways:

1. Close and re-open Visual Studio Code, or
2. Open the Command Pallet and type `Restart Omnisharp`.

OmniSharp tends to become confused if we restore dependencies from the command line instead of from within Visual Studio Code.

Comment: I did try to restart omnisharp, to no avail. I even tried re-installing the entire .net core SDK and Runtime. I think there's something funky with the project somewhere, but I can't see it.  I wish I could debug omnisharp to tell me why it can't find System...

Comment: Sometimes you have to **SAVE ALL** files in VS code before doing `dotnet build`.

Comment: I had an issue where a namespace that didn't exist kept popping up this helped.

Comment: Indeed, just like most microsoft products I suppose, it needs a restart of some kind. Too bad, VScode has potential, but these kind of actions make it useless. In fact, most code changes I make are not picked up, like they do for Java in IntelliJ or Eclipse. So better to use vim ;). thanks for the answer though, it worked. Note, handy to add command pallet shortcut is ctrol + shift + P.

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks. One more step after the restart command, a popup in the lower right asked if you wanted to rebuild dependencies. I clicked the rebuild button and all my libraries were again recognized.

Answer (score 19):

In VS Code on Fedora 30 with .NET Core 3.0 I had the same issue after create a worker project with **dotnet new worker**

First issue was that OmniSharp server didn't find the Sdks folder and the solution was include this line to the **~/.bashrc**:

```
export MSBuildSDKsPath="/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/$(dotnet --version)/Sdks"
```

then restart VS Code, but C# extension show me some messages like:

> The type or namespace name 'Collections' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

the solution was, first, in the terminal run:

```
dotnet build
```

then restart the OmniSharp server using the command palette (Ctrl+Shift+P):

```
OmniSharp: Restart OmniSharp
```

then I restart VS Code and the C# extensions and all dependencies are working fine.

Comment: yes the Restart OmniSharp after the build was key here

Answer (score 5):

If you are using the VS Code Extension 'C#' by Microsoft then try the following:-

For me doing the below two steps solved the issue:-

Go to File -> Preferences -> Settings

1. Search omnisharp.useModernNet and set to false
2. Search dotnet.server.useOmnisharp and set to true

Then Ctrl+Shift+P

-> Developer: Reload window

Comment: Thank you so much! This fixed an error that was driving me crazy where the linter would highlight the entire file, every time!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've figured out what was causing the issue. I was referencing the wrong imports for the framework part of the project.json file.

This:

```
"frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.1": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
          "type": "platform",
          "version": "1.1.0"
        }
      },
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  }
```

Should be this:

```
"frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.1": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  }
```

I'm on a windows 8 machine, and for some reason "dnxcore50" isn't valid, but "dotnet5.6" and "portable-net45+win8" is. I'm going to keep looking at the *why* for this question, but I am posting this answer now in case someone else is dealing with this problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you get this error, you could be missing a package.

> “The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found”

To add a package, you can run this command in the terminal:

```
dotnet add package
```

Example: Add Newtonsoft.Json NuGet package to a project:

```
dotnet add package Newtonsoft.Json
```

After that, go to the squiggly line, and add the missing reference by clicking on the lightbulb.

You can also install the Nuget Package Manager extension to find out what packages you need. See this answer to find out more:

[Install a Nuget package in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40675162/install-a-nuget-package-in-visual-studio-code)

Answer (score 1):

I'm using VS Code in a mac with OmniSharp and mono and the issue was gone after doing the following:

For MacOS and Linux users who have Mono installed, this means **you will need to set omnisharp.useGlobalMono to never** until a version of Mono ships with MSBuild 16.7.

Answer (score 0):

In my case vscode showed this error only for one file. The problem was solved by adding the missing file to the `Assembly-CSharp.csproj` I'm not sure when files are automatically added and when I do have to do it manually, but it solved this issue.

```
...
<ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Assets/Scripts/data/MissingFile.cs" />
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Same issue happened to me lot of times ..

in my case i opened the visual studio code as admin
then run the teriminal command `donet buid`
if required Restart OmniSharp (ctrl +shift + p)

Then It's working fine !!!

Answer (score 0):

Adding the configuration `"omnisharp.useModernNet": true` to the workspace *settings.json* solved the issue for me.

## TL;DR

In my scenario I had a development environment with preinstalled Visual Studio 2017/2019 but the new .NET 6.0 was missing.

To overcome the missing of .NET 6.0 I set the variable `omnisharp.useModernNet` to `false` within the "User Settings (JSON)". A long time passed and I forgot about it...

Later I installed the .NET 6.0 SDK and created a new project. But with the `useModernNet` set to `false` vscode (OmniSharp) was unable to resolve the missing assemblys for the (now new) .NET 6.0 SDK.

Long stroy short: Setting the value to `true` in my workspace *settings.json* solved the issue for me in this special case.

Answer (score -1):

Another possible cause of getting errors regarding "using System" is storing the `.vscode` directory in the git repository (my not adding it to `.gitignore`).

Opening the solution folder with VSCode can create cross version problems like the above and can be solved simply by deleting the `.vscode` directory.