# How to use pushsharp in existing c# project

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-code, nuget-package, pushsharp

There doesn't seem to be an installation guide in the [PushSharp readme](https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp) or the wiki link. I noticed that there's a NuGet installation for it, but I am not sure how it works. How would one incorporate it into an existing c# asp.NET project?

Edit:

It seems like the one from the NuGet package does not support dotNet core 1.1.

I found this that might support it: https://github.com/geeklearningio/PushSharp-Core

But I'm not sure how to incorporate this into my existing project.
Nevermind^ there's a NuGet package for the above, but it looks like its only support for dotnetcore2.0

Comment: Are you asking how to install a Nuget package?

Comment: Their github site appears to have a lot of very useful info.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40675162/install-a-nuget-package-in-visual-studio-code
- I followed this to install PushSharp into my project. I'm going to test it out now. First time installing a package into c# project so I wasn't sure how it worked. Thanks though everyone!