# CSC Compiling error CS0246 : Namespace not found

Tags: c#, netcoreapp3.1

I am unable to compile a .Net application.

The compiler gives the below error :

> " /.../, error **CS0246** : type or namespace 'MySql.Data' was not found. Are you missing an assembly reference ? /.../"

I'm using VSCode to do that. I tried making sure the .csproj file was in fact referencing the NuGet package, and all. I don't know what's the argument to reference a package defined in a .csproj, any help? Thanks a lot.

Comment: just add a reference to MySql.Data

Comment: Dude i said it in my post : i have made sure it was in fact referencing the mysql.data
Unless you're talking about an actual VS reference ?

Comment: Have you installed the [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data/) itself? Ho to do it in vs code you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40675162/2501279) for example.

Comment: Have you restored the packages for the project? If you are building without restoring packages, then even though you have a reference, you may not have the actual assemblies for the package.

Comment: @JamesFaix nope, I made sure I restored everything and even ran dotnet build but still the same error. 
I gave up already anyway.