# What should i do to connect and make queries to Heroku PostgreSQL from Unity/C#/vs code?

Tags: c#, postgresql, unity-game-engine, heroku, heroku-postgres

How to connect to Postgres db with Unity/C#? How to execute queries?
I have Postgres db on Heroku server (not localhost) and was able to work with it via python and psycopg2 but now i use Unity. I have all db credentials. Just do not know which library to use and how to install it.
I use Ubuntu and VS Code. I installed Nuget and Npgsql via Nuget but its classes are not visible in VS Code for some reason

Comment: It depends. Do you want to use hand made queries, micro ORM, ORM, ...?

Comment: Hand made @Klamsi

Comment: [Npgsql](https://www.npgsql.org/) maybe?

Comment: @Fliburt thanks, i want to check it out. however, i do not know yet how to make it work with VS Code + Ubuntu

Comment: Ok, i used this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40675162/install-a-nuget-package-in-visual-studio-code/47856617       to install nuget and (using nuget) npgsql

Comment: But there are many versions of npgsql. i have tried to install some, but classes are not accessible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found Npgsql.dll on dllme.com. I put it to Plugins folder that I created in Assets in Unity. That gave me some errors: Npgsql needed some dlls. I followed them and found those dlls on dllme.com and put them to Plugins also. And continued until there will be no errors. And it works now on my Ubuntu with local PostgreSQL DB.
I have 5 dlls in Plugins: Npgsql, System.Buffers, System.Memory, System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions