# How to use NodaTime in Visual Studio Code (Ubuntu)

Tags: c#, linux, ubuntu-20.04, nodatime

I want to try some coding in C# and thus `Visual Studio Code`, and I would like to stick with `NodaTime`.  With `Visual Studio` it is easy with `NodaTime`'s nuget package.. can't find similar in `Visual Studio Code`'s extensions.

I am using `Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS` and the `.NET Core SDK 5.0`.

Comment: It sounds like this isn't really about Noda Time, but just "using NuGet packages in Visual Studio code", right? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40675162

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Jon Skeet, as he mentions, by following the link he posted, run this in your Visual Studio Code terminal:

`dotnet add package NodaTime`