# How install Oracle package for Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll in VS Code

Tags: oracle, powershell, visual-studio-code, package

I'm trying to install the above package in VS Code.  For some reason when I put this at the top of my script I get an error message.

```
using namespace system.collections.generic
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Data.OracleClient
Add-Type  -Path "C:\Users\me\OneDrive - company\Documents\2021\temp endToEnd\oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core\oracle.manageddataaccess.core.3.21.50\lib\netstandard2.1\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll"
```

Error:

```
Add-Type : Missing an argument for parameter 'AssemblyName'. Specify a parameter of type 'System.String[]' and try again.
```

I also tried `Add-type -Path "C:\Users\me\OneDrive - company\Documents\2021\temp endToEnd\oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core\oracle.manageddataaccess.core.3.21.50\lib\netstandard2.1\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll"`

And it had this error:

```
Add-Type : Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
```

My question is, how do I load this, so I can do the following:

```
$connectionString = "Data Source=$dataSource;User Id=$username;Password=$password;" 
$con = New-Object Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection($connectionString)
```

I am trying to install this package because I have this error when I try to execute the last code line above:

```
New-Object : Cannot find type [Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection]: verify that the assembly containing this type is loaded.
```

I tried doing it through nuget manager as well, with ctrl shift P, nuget manager, but it's not coming up in the list that I can see (odp.net, oracle managed..., etc).

I had download this from the oracle website:

> oracle.manageddataaccess.core.3.21.50.nupkg

Then I used 7-zip to unzip it to the location I'm Add-Type from.

I've been looking at these links:
[New-object Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/2fc345f8-4598-4703-971f-a2537f39a3bb/systemdataoracleclient-and-powershell?forum=winserverpowershell)

[oracle-developer-tools-vs-code](https://medium.com/oracledevs/oracle-developer-tools-for-vs-code-f26d31535925)

[install nuget package in vs code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40675162/install-a-nuget-package-in-visual-studio-code)

I can't seem to get this installed so the command works in the script.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The first trick is to download the correct `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll`, once you have that then `add-type -path (join-path $DownloadedPath 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll')` will work without installing the oracle client.

Answer (score 1):

You're basically treating powershell like a client application, you'll want: the Oracle Data Application Client(ODAC) driver, powershell is a managed memory model so you'll want the managed one, and most likely the 64-bit one unless for some reason you're running 32-bit powershell... Beyond that it'll likely depend on which version works best for your Oracle database.

For example 12cR1:

Download [ODP.NET_Managed_ODAC122cR1.zip](https://www.oracle.com/ro/database/technologies/odac-downloads.html)

extract `odp.net\managed\common\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll`

```
PS C:\working> add-type -path (ls .\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll).FullName
PS C:\working> $OraEntry = '(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(Host=database.example.com)(Port=1234)))(CONNECT_DATA=(service_name=BigData)))'
PS C:\working> $con = [Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection]::new()
PS C:\working> $con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=$OraEntry;User Id=$username;Password=$password"
PS C:\working> $con.Open()
```

If you don't know what the OraEntry should be you can likely copy it from your `tnsnames.ora` and/or check with your database admin

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [How the Runtime Locates Assemblies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/deployment/how-the-runtime-locates-assemblies)

Most common .NET assemblies are loaded either from **current directory** or from **Global Assembly Cache (GAC)**. The GAC takes precedence over locally stored files.

Check files in your downloaded package, there should be the `OraProvCfg.exe`. Use it for adding the dll into GAC and doing the configuration:

```
OraProvCfg.exe /action:config /product:odpm /frameworkversion:v4.0.30319 /providerpath:"C:\Users\me\OneDrive - company\Documents\2021\temp endToEnd\oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core\oracle.manageddataaccess.core.3.21.50\lib\netstandard2.1\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll"
```

Comment: I don't see OraProvCfg.exe in my downloaded package.  Do you have a link for what I should download that has what I need? I do see my Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll though. Any suggestions?

Comment: Check https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/dotnet-odacdeploy-downloads.html - it is included in the "XCopy" versions.